# Django booleanfield modelform

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

So I'm making a to-do list and I made a booleanfield modelform which has attribute "complete". I want that user to check it when it's complete and I tried wriring if task.complete == True cross out the item and it didn't work(it only worked when I checked it from the admin panel). Then I tried form.complete instead of task.complete and it doesn't do anything.

models:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms:

```
from .models import *

class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Add new task...'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'
```

html:

```
<div class="main-container">
            <form method="POST" action="/">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="submit"/>
                {{ form.title }}
            </form>
            {% for task in tasks %}
              {{ form.complete }}
              {% if form.complete == True %}
                <h1><strike>{{task.title}}</strike></h1>
              {% else %}
                <h1>{{task.title}}</h1>
              {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

views:

```
def index(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.order_by('-created')
    form = TaskForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/')

    context = {
        'tasks': tasks,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'to-do.html', context)
```

[image: and this is the screenshot of my project(checkbox is checked but the task is not crossed out)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with your code I don't know how to explain. Try this. It should work.

```
<div class="main-container">
            <form method="POST" action="/">  # create new task
                {% csrf_token %}
                
                {{ form.title }}
                <input type="submit" name="new-task"/>
            </form>
            <form method="post"> # update task status
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for task in tasks %}              
              {% if task.complete %}
              <input type="checkbox" name="if_completed" checked value="{{ task.pk }}">
                <h1><strike>{{task.title}}</strike></h1>
              {% else %}
               <input type="checkbox" name="if_completed" value="{{ task.pk }}">
                <h1>{{task.title}}</h1>
              {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}
                <input type="submit" name="update-task"/>
          </form>
        </div>
```

view.py (Only for form, add your other code with it)

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

def index(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.order_by('-created')
    form = TaskForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'new-task' in request.POST:
            form = TaskForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home')) # replace home with url name where you want to redirect

        elif 'update-task' in request.POST:
            task_pk = request.POST.getlist("if_completed")
            for i in task_pk:
                Task.objects.filter(pk=i).update(complete=True)  # I have replace pk with i here
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))  # replace home with url name where you want to redirect

    context = {
        'tasks': tasks,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'to-do.html', context)
```

in forms.py

```
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('title',)
        widgets = {
           'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Add new task...'})
        }
```

This should work. There may be be some error because of typos or indentation. Let me know if you get any issue

Comment: yeah now I'm getting error **The view tasks.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.**

Comment: after form has processed return something. you can return on same page

Comment: I posted it as an answer. check it out

Answer (score 0):

```
def index(request):
   tasks = Task.objects.order_by('-created')
   form = TaskForm()
   context = {
    'tasks': tasks,
    'form': form,
    }
   if request.method == 'POST':
      if 'new-task' in request.POST:
          form = TaskForm(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
             form.save()

      elif 'update-task' in request.POST:
         task_pk = request.POST.getlist("if_completed")
         for i in task_pk:
             Task.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(complete=True)

      return render(request, 'to-do.html', context)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error **Reverse for '/' not found. '/' is not a valid view function or pattern name.** on line 22 where I changed "home" with '/' and I also tried ' '

Comment: I replaced ``return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))`` with ``return HttpResponseRedirect('/')`` and it works, the task gets crossed out, but checkbox disappears, but I guess that's okay.

Comment: Code is not showing checkbox for completed task. check this line {% if task.complete %}

Comment: I did, but there is no line that says to hide the checkbox if **completed = True**. What should I change to make it visible even when the task is completed?

Comment: I have updated template code. Please check